# 2D Fourier transform of exponentials and cosines

Tags: fourier-analysis

I would like to know the 2D FT of the following functions:

1.$$\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y+a)^2}{b^2}\right)$$

2.$$\exp\left(-\frac{(x-y+a)^2}{b^2}\right)\cos\left(n\pi\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\cos\left(n\pi\left(y+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!